# What does GET mean in PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I recently discovered that GET is a reserved word in SQLDeveloper,but I can't figure out what it's for. Tried [oracle help center's list of reserved words](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/reservewords.htm) but there's no mention of it.

In short: What is the use of GET in PLSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything in PL/SQL, unless you have an object with that name. Or in SQL.

It's a [SQL*Plus command](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve024.htm#SQPUG045):

> GET [FILE] file_name[.ext] [LIST | NOLIST]
>
> Loads an operating system file into the SQL buffer.

You can get a file into the buffer and edit it there before executing it, rather than just running it directly with `start` or `@`.

SQL Developer implements, or at least recognises or allows, most SQL*Plus statements, presumably for compatibility reasons (though some things don't work, such as `set embed on`).

It seems to silently ignore `get`.

It's in the documentation's [keyword list](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/sql_keywords-g.htm), rather than the reserved words list. You can use it as an object name etc.; [they recommend you don't](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/ap_keywd002.htm#SQLRF55622), but as this is a client keyword rather than a SQL one it wouldn't be as noticeable. At least, if SQL Developer didn't highlight it as a keyword...